# Get path of an element inside a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, search

I have an object like the following :

```
[
  {
    "uid": "aaa-aaa",
    "name": "foo",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "uid": "aaa-bbb",
    "name": "bar",
    "children": [
      {
        "uid": "aaa-bbc",
        "name": "baz",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "uid": "aaa-ccc",
        "name": "fooz",
        "children": [
          {
            "uid": "aaa-bcb",
            "name": "Yeah !",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to write a function that would take that object an `uid` as parameters and would return a path to the element with the `uid` in that object (or `null` if it's not found).

Something like this :

```
> getElementPath(bigObject, 'aaa-bcb')
[1, "children", 1, "children", 0]
or
> getElementPath(bigObject, 'aaa-bcb')
[1, 1, 0]
```

I know the function has to be recursive since there should be no limit in nesting levels. I have tried this but it always returns `null` :

```js
function getElementPath (haystack, uid, currentPath = []) {
  if (haystack.uid === uid) {
    return currentPath
  }
  if (Array.isArray(haystack.children)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < haystack.children.length; i++) {
      let newPath = [...currentPath, i]
      let path = getElementPath(haystack.children[i], uid, newPath)
      if (path !== null) {
        return path
      }
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: If you will have to use this `getElementPath()` function very often, it would make sense to reduce the array into an object once so you have direct access to any element. That might remove the need altogether to have the full path.

Comment: Your "following object" is an array. That array passed to function `getElementPath` as `haystack`, then in the first condition `haystack.uid === uid` there `haystack` is an array, and in the next condition `haystack.children` is undefined for the same reason. The only one `return` statement left which eventually return null. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `flat`

Flatten the object and then loop over the Object keys until you find the one that has the appropriate value. Once you find it, the key is the path.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat

My (naive and quick) implementation would look like this. But what I don't love about it is that it knows to look at the "children" property, it's fine if you're data structure is well defined and doesn't change very often, the `flat` idea will work no matter if you change your data structure or not.

```
getPathForUid = (uid,obj,thisPath = []) => {

    if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.reduce((acc,item,idx) => getPathForUid(uid,item,thisPath.concat(idx)),[]);
    }

    return obj.uid === uid ? thisPath : getPathForUid(uid,obj.children,thisPath.concat('children'));

}
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution but I would like if possible not to add dependencies to my project (also, I am very curious about what's wrong in my implementation)

Comment: Write less code, use more **small** libraries - your code will never be as well (battle)tested as `flat` :) I *highly* recommend flat (and a companion library - [property-expr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/property-expr)) if you're doing a lot of object-mapping work, just like I'd recommend lodash.

Comment: That's a good general recommendation for writing better software (and faster) but my goal here is to be a better coder myself. I am free enough for spending time trying to debug my implementation and I came here for help trying to understand what is wrong with it. Note that I will probably end up using `flat` but I would really feel better when I am able to write that function I need

Comment: I found what was wrong in my case : the main object should not be an array itself, it should be an object containing a `children` key.

Comment: @KiJéy - what is this all about? `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentPath))` edit: I get it, you don't want to mutate the array - you could (should) just do `const newPath = [...currentPath,i];`

Comment: Yeah I'm old school xD. Thanks for the advice, I'll update now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function getObject(listaJson, uid) {
    var object = null,
        param,
        type = null;

    if (listaJson.uid === uid) {
        return listaJson;
    }

    for (param in listaJson) {
        type = typeof(listaJson[param]);

        if (type.toString().toLowerCase() === 'object') {
            object = getObject(listaJson[param], uid);
        }

        if (object) {
            return object;
        }
    }

    return object;
}

console.log(getObject(json, 'aaa-aaa'));
console.log(getObject(json, 'aaa-bbb'));
console.log(getObject(json, 'aaa-bbc'));
console.log(getObject(json, 'aaa-ccc'));
console.log(getObject(json, 'aaa-bcb'));
console.log(getObject(json, 'aaa-xxx')); // null
console.log(getObject(json, 'yyy-jjj')); // null
```

Comment: I don't want the object but the path to the object